# Turn off SSLv3 on JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: ssl, jboss, jboss7.x, poodle-attack, sslv3

I have Spring MVC App running on JBoss AS 7.1.1. I need to turn off SSLv3 to protect against Poodle vulnerability. JBoss documentation at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1232233 suggests I need to make sure that SSLv3 is not listed in the SSL Protocol attributes.

I have tried that but I can still connect to my website after only enabling SSL in Internet explorer options displayed below. Below is my standalone.xml configuration:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
     <ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="secret" certificate-key-file="C:\Dev\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\foo.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
</connector>
```

Can someone suggest what I'm missing here?

[image]

Comment: Consider updating your question with relevant sections from your configuration and the error you're seeing. Also, I'm assuming you tried this with "Use TLS 1.0", "Use TLS 1.1" and "Use TLS 1.2" enabled in IE and with "Use SSL 3.0" disabled. Is that correct?

Comment: I have updated the question with the incorrect configuration I was using. And,I was never seeing an error - I needed to disable SSLv3 but was not able to. I have successfully fixed this now, please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured a way to fix it. If you change 'protocol' to 'protocols' in the above mentioned configuration and make sure sslv3 is **not** in the protocol list then it disables SSLv3.

Notice the **protocols** attribute in the config below

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
     <ssl name="foo-ssl" key-alias="foo" password="secret" certificate-key-file="C:\Dev\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\foo.keystore" protocol="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>
</connector>
```

After making this change, if you open IE and disable all other protocols except SSL 3.0  - and then try to access the web page, you should not be able see the web page.

More details available here: http://abhirampal.com/2015/07/23/disable-ssl-v3-on-jboss-as-7-1-1/